# Cert says revoked on firefox but not on ssl certificate verify sites

Tags: certificate

Using https://www.ssllabs.com it tells me my cert is revoked, firefox also says my cert is revoked

But using https://www.sslshopper.com it says my cert is fine
and I'm able to access it on Chrome

I've tried contacting GoDaddy because I believe the revocation information (CRL/OCSP) is provided by them but they directed me elsewhere

I'm not sure what other situations can cause this problem without having to rekey the cert and try again

Comment: [Chrome handles revocation checking differently](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/180938/revoked-cert-not-showing-revoked-in-chrome-64-0-3282-186) (and by coincidence the example there is also godaddy). SSLLabs is usually reliable; if you don't know enough to check yourself and don't trust people here (or security.SX) to check, I'd say that's as good as you're going to get.

Comment: yeah thanks I just ended up rekeying